# Change another div on hover which is not sibling nor child

Tags: html, css, hover, parent-child, siblings

My HTML code is similar to this :

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="btn-section btn-1">
        <p class="section pro">...</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="navbar">
    <div class="btn-section btn-2">
        <p class="section notpro">...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using this in my CSS code :

```
.btn-1:hover {
    .pro {
        ...
    }
}
```

It works perfectly.

What I want to do now is to modify my .notpro class inside the btn-1:hover. As .notpro is not child or sibling with btn-1, it doesn't work.

```
.btn-1:hover {
    .pro {
        ... // works
    }
    .notpro {
        ... // doesn't work
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way without using javascript to affect a different  non-sibling selector. But you an do it if you move the hover up one level.

You need to put the hover on the first navbar and using the direct sibling combinator (`+`) - target the other navbar and then inside it to get the .notpro element. Note that I added words to your elements to show the hover effect.

The only other CSS way of doing this is to put both elements inside the one navbar - then they are siblings and can be targetted.

```css
.navbar:hover + .navbar .notpro {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="btn-section btn-1">
        <p class="section pro">I am a Pro</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="navbar">
    <div class="btn-section btn-2">
        <p class="section notpro">I am Not a Pro</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I can't use the first solution because I need the hover to activate only when the mouse is over "btn-section", which is smaller than "navbar" (I didn't copy my whole code, I have more stuff there).
This issue with the second one is that I need to separate them to place them correctly in my page.

I'll search how to do this in JS. Will I need more than simple EventListeners ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this syntax is valid in CSS, meaning selector inside another selector.

You can add :hover to the 'pro' to get different behaviour than the parent div.

Comment: Not really clear what you mean in first sentence. **Literally** it is simply wrong to say that CSS will baulk at something like *nav li .droplink:hover* just because you have 3 layers of selectors before the *:hover* pseudoclass. Multiple nested selectors is ubiquitous in CSS. But none of this addresses the OP question anyway.